# Проблема со слайдером на Owl Carousel

Tags: javascript

Подключил owlCarousel.js... 
Задал контейнер .slider, задал стили.

Создал 3 item... Но они все на одной странице. Да, слайдер работает, но прокручивает на пустую страницу, а 3 айтема на одном экране.

Прописал в common.js следующий код:

```
$(function() {

$(".slider").owlCarousel({      

            items : 1
});
```

});

Comment: Поясните подробнее, чего добиваетесь от слайдера и что вместо этого получилось. Добавьте скриншот, полный код слайдера, ссылку на страницу с ошибкой.

Comment: парадокс. Сегодня запустил сервер на локалхосте - все как вчера - и все заработало )))